# Should I always create my DynamoDB tables using hash and range primary key type?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In the docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/APISummary.html) it states:

> You can query only tables whose primary key is of hash-and-range type

and

> we recommend that you design your applications so that you can use the Query operation mostly, and use Scan only where appropriate

It's not directly stated, but does this make it best practice to use hash-and-range primary keys?

EDIT:

Answer TL;DR: Use whichever primary key type that makes sense for your data model and use secondary indexes for better querying support.

References:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2013/12/dynamodb-global-secondary-indexes.html

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=604862

[In what situation do you use Simple Hash Keys on DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713369/in-what-situation-do-you-use-simple-hash-keys-on-dynamodb)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The choice of which key to use comes down to your Use Cases and Data Requirements for a particular scenario. For example, if you are storing *User Session* Data it might not make much sense using the *Range Key* since each record could be referenced by a GUID and accessed directly with no grouping requirements. In general terms once you know the Session Id you just get the specific item querying by the key. Another example could be storing User Account or Profile data, each user has his own and you most likely will access it directly (by User Id or something else).

However, if you are storing *Order Items* then the *Range Key* makes much more sense since you probably want to retrieve the items grouped by their *Order*.

In terms of the *Data Model*, the *Hash Key* allows you to uniquely identify a record from your table, and the *Range Key* can be optionally used to group and sort several records that are usually retrieved together. Example: If you are defining an Aggregate to store *Order Items*, the *Order Id* could be your *Hash Key*, and the *OrderItemId* the *Range Key*. Whenever you would like to search the *Order Items* from a particular *Order*, you just query by the Hash Key (Order Id), and you will get all your *order items*.

You can find below a formal definition for the use of these two keys:

> "Composite Hash Key with Range Key allows the developer to create a
>   primary key that is the composite of two attributes, a 'hash
>   attribute' and a 'range attribute.' When querying against a composite
>   key, the hash attribute needs to be uniquely matched but a range
>   operation can be specified for the range attribute: e.g. all orders
>   from Werner in the past 24 hours, or all games played by an individual
>   player in the past 24 hours." [[VOGELS]](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2013/12/dynamodb-global-secondary-indexes.html)

So the *Range Key* adds a grouping capability to the *Data Model*, however, the use of these two keys also have an implication on the *Storage Model*:

> "Dynamo uses consistent hashing to partition its key space across its
>   replicas and to ensure uniform load distribution. A uniform key
>   distribution can help us achieve uniform load distribution assuming
>   the access distribution of keys is not highly skewed."
>   [[DDB-SOSP2007]](http://www.journalofcloudcomputing.com/content/pdf/2192-113X-2-22.pdf)

Not only the *Hash Key* allows to uniquely identify the record, but also is the mechanism to ensure load distribution. The *Range Key* (when used) helps to indicate the records that will be mostly retrieved together, therefore, the storage can also be optimized for such need.

Choosing the correct keys to represent your data is one of the most critical aspects during your design process, and it directly impacts how much your application will perform, scale and cost.

---

Footnotes:

- The Data Model is the model through which we perceive and manipulate our data. It describes how we interact with the data in the database [FOWLER]. In other words, it is how you abstract your data model, the way you group your entities, the attributes that you choose as primary keys, etc
- The Storage Model describes how the database stores and manipulates the data internally [FOWLER]. Although you cannot control this directly, you can certainly optimize how the data is retrieved or written by knowing how the database works internally.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I understand I can access items in a hash-key table using by their hash key, but the problem then becomes determining the hash key of the item. Take a simple example of when a user logs in with email and password and the primary key is `userId`. At time of login, I do not know the `userId` and need to do a query on `email`. (I could use `email` as primary key but then I can't lookup by `userId`). I haven't dug deep enough yet to get a full handle on local and global indexes, but I feel like my answer may be there.

Comment: According to the article you linked to on Vogels' blog, it looks like GSI is what I'm looking for.

"Moreover, a GSI's performance is designed to meet DynamoDB's single digit millisecond latency - you can add items to a Users table for a gaming app with tens of millions of users with UserId as the primary key, but retrieve them based on their home city, with no reduction in query performance."

Comment: The examples in Vogels' blog use hash-and-range type primary keys. Could the same be achieved with just hash primary keys?

Comment: Okay I think I have this. Could you confirm this for me? I can create `user` table with `userId` as the hash primary key (no range). I can then create a GSI `UserEmailIndex` with a primary key of `email` which will give me `userId` (since primary keys are always projected into GSIs). I can then get the `userId` by querying `UserEmailIndex` with the provided `email`, and then using the `userId` I can get the item from the `user` table.

Comment: You can also use email as the hash key (instead of userId) since it will be unique.

Comment: I mentioned that in my first comment but then I would have the problem of not being able to look up by userId. I think the best case is to set the primary key to whichever is used most frequently (say for example querying by userId is more common than querying by email) and then create GSIs to provide additional querying support.

Comment: Why do you need to query by userId? Can you somehow take some actions to remove that use case?

Comment: I am only saying that because small details in your data model can mean a lot in the long run... adding a conditional or one index here and there might not seem a big deal but I would save additional complexity to your biggest challenges. However, if you really need to have two ways to retrieve the user information, by all means use the GSI, but I would only take that as my last resort.

Comment: Say I have a REST resource `GET /users/1` I could easily query for `userId` 1.  That would be far more common than querying by email which I would mainly use for logging in.

Comment: It makes sense, you could have a table with email#password as the hash key and the userId as an attribute ... your login process would try to do a simple GetItem with the calculated hash key, if the userId is returned you not only have the confirmation of the authentication process but also the key to retrieve other user information.

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily. It is best to choose a primary key that supports the access patterns for your use case.

For example, let's say you want to have a table for **Users**. You will store the details for a single user (name, email, creator, etc.). Your access pattern might be that you are fetching the details for a specific *User*. In this case it makes more sense to use a primary key of type **hash**, with a hash key of **userId**.

Let's say you also want another table that stores **Groups**. Your access pattern might be that you want to get all members for a given group. Here, it makes more sense to use a primary key of type **hash and range**, with your hash and range keys respectively being **groupId** and **userId**.

The important things to know are the [differences between both key types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.PrimaryKey) (quote below) and the [Guidelines for Working with Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html):

> - **Hash Type Primary Key**—The primary key is made of one attribute, a    hash attribute. DynamoDB builds an unordered hash index on this
>     primary key attribute. Each item in the table is uniquely identified
>     by its hash key value.
> - **Hash and Range Type Primary Key**—The primary key is made of two    attributes. The first attribute is the hash attribute and the second
>     one is the range attribute. DynamoDB builds an unordered hash index
>     on the hash primary key attribute, and a sorted range index on the
>     range primary key attribute. Each item in the table is uniquely
>     identified by the combination of its hash and range key values. It is 
>     possible for two items to have the same hash key value, but those two 
>     items must have different range key values.

You can see more about best practices in the Dynamo DB [Guidelines for Working with Tables documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html)

Comment: Thanks! After commenting on @spin's answer I look to yours and see you use the exact example I used. I understand the differences between Hash and Hash-and-Range, but my difficulty is with querying a table using a Hash Type Primary Key. Say for example I want to look up a user on login by email, and I don't yet have the userId, how best do I go about that? Perhaps the answer is in secondary indexes which I haven't fully grasped yet, but that part of the docs makes it seem like doing a `Query` on a table that uses Hash Primary Key is impossible.

Comment: I used `userId` as my example, but you just as easily use `emailAddress` as the hash key (depends on your design and access). Let's say you have `emailAddress` as the **hash** key for the table. When you want to access an item from this table using `emailAddress`, you would make a `GetItem` call. You *can't query this table on just the `emailAddress`*. If you need to access  this table using other attribute(s) as the key, you will have to create an index and query against that index. That index can also be of either **hash** / **hash-range**, and you set the attributes to be projected onto it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware I could use `email` as my hash key, but my most common use case is looking up by `userId`. Say I have a REST resource `GET /users/1` I could easily query for `userId` 1.  That would be far more common than querying by email which I would mainly use for logging in. Hypothetically, if I was to say "the only time I want to query by email is on login" would it be better to do a conditional Scan instead of creating a secondary index? I understand a Scan would be far more expensive, but since it is a relatively rare action that would probably be okay, right? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said - no you should not.

The statement that confused and caused you to ask this question in the first place is **wrong**:

> You can query only tables whose primary key is of hash-and-range type

You can query tables whose primary key is of single-attribute (only partition) type.

Proof:

```bash
# Create single-attribute primary key table
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name testdb6 --attribute-definitions '[{"AttributeName": "Id", "AttributeType": "S"}]' --key-schema '[{"AttributeName": "Id", "KeyType": "HASH"}]' --provisioned-throughput '{"ReadCapacityUnits": 5, "WriteCapacityUnits": 5}' 

# Populate table
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name testdb6 --item '{ "Id": {"S": "1"}, "LastName": {"S": "Lopez"}, "FirstName": {"S": "Maria"}}'
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name testdb6 --item '{ "Id": {"S": "2"}, "LastName": {"S": "Fernandez"}, "FirstName": {"S": "Augusto"}}'

# Query table using only partition attribute
aws dynamodb query --table-name testdb6 --select ALL_ATTRIBUTES --key-conditions '{"Id": {"AttributeValueList": [{"S": "1"}], "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"}}'
```

Output of the last command (it works):

```js
{
"Count": 1,
"Items": [
    {
        "LastName": {
            "S": "Lopez"
        },
        "Id": {
            "S": "1"
        },
        "FirstName": {
            "S": "Maria"
        }
    }
],
"ScannedCount": 1,
"ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```